# Mutex fails sporadically

Tags: c#

I have a brand new app that I am developing.  I am the only person using it, so it's impossible that I have contention with another person.  Yet, even at that, `Mutex` is often failing.  Here is my code sample.

```
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MS_NBR"))
{
 System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Before " + @"Global\MS_NBR");
 if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), false))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
 System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("After " + @"Global\MS_NBR");
  ..Here I assign a unique member number..  (runs in a fraction of a second)
 mutex.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

This works from time to time, but very frequently throws the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which indicates to me, that it could not obtain a Mutex in 30 seconds.

Comment: The error you are receiving indicates the using line where you new up the Mutex?

Comment: @AlG No it's when `WaitOne` returns false and the OP throws an exception.

Comment: You are the only application using the `Mutex` but are you calling this routine on various threads? Are the threads looping?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This section may not apply, but I would give it a try nonetheless. I've never used a named mutex, instead statically allocated ones, and have never had any issues.

With this line:

```
using (Mutex mutex = ...
```

you allocate a named global `Mutex` and dispose of it when the `using {}` clause ends.

It may be helpful to define it statically, instead:

```
private static Mutex mutex = ...
```

Never dispose of it, never recreate it. It must be just one object that lives as long as the application runs.

Comment: He is using a named mutex, so the fact that he re-instantiates it each time should not affect exclusivity.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that one.